# Entity Framework - The underlying provider failed on ConnectionString

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, entity-framework, connection

While using the Entity Framework I have split it out to it's own project:

- RivWorks.Model - Contains Entity Model
- RivWorks.Controller - Uses the Entity Model and contains the biz rules
- RivWorks.View.Web - The web site
- RivWorks.View.Services - WCF project

Everything in the web site is working fine.  I am able to call into the Controller and get a valid Model back.  When I try the same thing from the Web.Service I am getting this error:

> ERROR:
>   The underlying provider failed on ConnectionString.
>   STACK TRACE:
>     at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString)
>     at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
>     at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateEntityConnection(String connectionString)
>     at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(String connectionString, String defaultContainerName)
>     at RivWorks.Model.Entities.RivFeedsEntities1..ctor(String connectionString)
>     at RivWorks.Model.FeedStoreReadOnly..ctor(String connectionString)
>     at RivWorks.Controller.ProductManager.LookupProduct(String productID, String sku, String urlRef, String env, String logPath)

I am a bit confused as to why and digging through the error logs I finally figured out the connection strings were not being read from the Web Site's config file.  So, I added some code to catch that and, for now, hard coded the values in.  Like:

```
public dataObjects.NegotiateSetup LookupProduct(string productID, string sku, string urlRef, string env, string logPath)
{
    string feedConnString = "";
    string rivConnString = "";

    log.InitializeLogFile(logPath);
    dataObjects.NegotiateSetup resultSet = new dataObjects.NegotiateSetup();

    try { feedConnString = AppSettings.FeedAutosEntities_connString; }
    catch { feedConnString = @"metadata=res://*/Entities.FeedEntities.csdl|res://*/Entities.FeedEntities.ssdl|res://*/Entities.FeedEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=***.***.***.***;Initial Catalog=******;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=******;Password=&quot;******&quot;;MultipleActiveResultSets=True'"; }

    try { rivConnString = AppSettings.RivWorkEntities_connString; }
    catch { rivConnString = @"metadata=res://*/Entities.RivEntities.csdl|res://*/Entities.RivEntities.ssdl|res://*/Entities.RivEntities.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='Data Source=******;Initial Catalog=******_Dev;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=******;Password=&quot;******&quot;;MultipleActiveResultSets=True'"; }

    try
    {
        using (RivFeedsEntities1 _dbFeed = new FeedStoreReadOnly(feedConnString).ReadOnlyEntities())
        {
            using (RivEntities _dbRiv = new RivWorksStore(rivConnString).NegotiationEntities())
            {
```

But, alas, it is still giving me the above error!  Any ideas why?

Comment: Found a thread on MSDN that is unanswered after more than a year.  Sad, very, very sad.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adodotnetentityframework/thread/c5a7a766-9b02-4ae2-be60-a2605983701d?prof=required

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know you've been mucking around with your connection strings to sanitize them but I'm guessing you didn't put the `&quot;`'s around the password in?

Are they actually required?

Comment: EntityFramework stores its connection strings something like that, although mine have `&quot;` from `provider connection string=` which could be where Keith's going wrong: `metadata=res://*/Models.DoodleEF.csdl|res://*/Models.DoodleEF.ssdl|res://*/Models.DoodleEF.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=zhpCoreContent;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;"`

Comment: They are copied straight out of the App.Config.  I did the same thing for web.config - but wait - hard coded does not understand &quot;.  <doh/>.  Will give that a shot in the morning.

Comment: Man, I wish I had another developer here who can look at code and see the simple mistakes buried inside of a string.  Thanks guys!  I replaced &quot; with string quotes and the Context now builds.  Off to the next error.

Comment: Yeah I hear yah... it is sooooo easy to overlook things by yourself.

Comment: Can anyone say for certain exactly where the &quots are coming from?  I'd sure love to put an automated end to that, rather than having to always remember "this exception always means go remove the &quots."

Comment: I had another syntax issue on the ConnectionString. I just fixed it and now it's working =)

Answer (score -1):

Double check your connection string is correct, little typo's can cause this same error.

This is wrong:

```
 <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/OnlineAB.csdl|res://*/OnlineAB.ssdl|res://*/OnlineABSuperAdmin.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source.;initial catalog=
```

This is right:

```
 <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/OnlineAB.csdl|res://*/OnlineAB.ssdl|res://*/OnlineABSuperAdmin.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=.;initial catalog=
```

See after the **DataSource** I was missing an equal sign.